# What path of PHPUnit add as Global Include Path in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, phpunit, composer-php

My book tell to add PHPUnit path to Global Include Path in Netbeans, but its use out of date PEAR way.

I installed PHPUnit using `composer global require "phpunit/phpunit xxx"`. I run this command right in `c:\`

I got main PHPunit directory in: `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit`

and two files in:
`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, on how much code-completion support you want.

- If you want the code-completion to work for **all globally installed Composer packages**,
  then the path would be

  `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor`

  When you set this "Include Path" Netbeans will automatically scan the whole vendor folder and provide completion support for all classes of all packages. Scanning might take a while...
- If you want completion support **only for PHPUnit**, then adding

  `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit`

  is sufficent. Only the content of the phpunit folder will be scanned.

  (I use the first approach, because PHPUnit has several other dependencies/packages (e.g. phpunit-selenium) and its nice to have support for these classes, too.)
- The bin folder should contain a batch file: `phpunit.bat`.
  This script might be used in the testing/ phpunit configuration as the "PHPUnit Script". When you invoke testing, this script will be used to start the Composer installed PHPUnit (, instead of the PEAR one).